# How to copy local directory to external drive and ensure file integrity while multiple computer unexpected restarts can happen. rsync, other?

Tags: rsync, backup

My computer has restarts often unexpectedly. I am trying to backup data to external drive. Is the *rsync* best tool for that kind of job that can ensure file data integrity? If yes, what command should I run on initial synchronization and synchronizations after unexpected restarts? If not, which tool to use and how?

Comment: Make sure both drives/volumes use the same filesystem, or at least filesystems which are compatible to each other. Then you may just use `cp -au sourcedir destdir`, example: `cp -au . /mnt/backup` - depending on your filesystem structure, you might want to add the parameter `-x` too, like `cp -aux sourcedir destdir`. `-x` ensures that only files from the filesystem are copied where `sourcedir` is located.

Comment: PS take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339287/copy-or-rsync-command